# Is it considered bad practice to throw errors in a JavaScript class?

Tags: javascript, class, exception, ecmascript-6

I have a JavaScript class like the following and I need to control the data type of my input variables.

```
class Store
{
    constructor (name)
    {
        if (typeof name !== "string")
            throw new Error("The first argument must be a string!");

        createStore(name);
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Is it considered a bad practice? There is a better solution?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be good practice? Failing fast is good.

Comment: It depends on your intention for this `Store`. Do you want the entire control flow to be interrupted for a type checker? IMO, it might make sense to return the error and let the user decide what they want to do with it.

Comment: Alternatively, you could look into `Flow`, which is a library that enforces static types in function args: https://flow.org/

Comment: @BobbyMatson - You can't easily return an error from a constructor because the constructor returns the object.  You could return `null` and require all code to check for that, but exceptions are pretty much ideal for this use.  Exceptions also tend to be a lot more visible to programmers who make a mistake in development than just returning an error code that probably isn't being checked for.  99% of the time, this type of error is a programming error, not a run-time error with properly written code so you want the error to be in the developer's face immediately so they can fix their code.

Comment: Agreed! I totally missed that this was in the constructor - that makes total sense. As a developer I would expect `new Store(123)` to throw an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in some cases it might actually be better to not throw the error.
Let's say you have a method that returns a promise. In that case you would probably be better off rejecting it so that it can be be caught using `.catch`.

```
class Example {
    test(name) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            if (typeof name !== "string")
                reject("The first argument must be a string!")
            else
                resolve()
        })
    }
}

let ex = new Example()
ex.test(['array']).then( () => {
    console.log('We successfully passed a string!')
}).catch( err => {
    console.error(err)
})
```